# Jquery DataTable Reset multiple search columns

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I've manage to reset the columns with a button click but the table doesnt refresh.

For example, lets say there's 10 records on the table and i search 2 different columns so that the table now shows 2 records.

If i click the button to reset, it clears the text but it still only shows 2 records on the table. If i then type anything into the input field to search, it will then show all 10 records.

Why do i have to type something, should it just reset the table after i click the button?

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  var table = $('#everyonesTable').DataTable({
    colReorder:         true,
    stateSave:          true,
    "lengthMenu": [
      [10],
      [10]
    ],

    scrollX:            true,
    scrollCollapse:     true,
    paging:             true,
    fixedColumns:       true,
    dom: ' <"top"B>rt<"bottom"fpi><"clear">',

    buttons: [{
      "extend": 'colvis',
      "collectionLayout": 'fixed four-column'
    }],
  });

  new $.fn.dataTable.Buttons(table, {
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Clear Filters',
        action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
          $("[data-index='1']").val('');
          $("[data-index='2']").val('');
          $("[data-index='3']").val('');
          var datatable = $('#everyonesTable').dataTable().api();

          $.get('myUrl', function(newDataArray) {
            datatable.clear();
            datatable.rows.add(newDataArray);
            datatable.draw();
          });
        }
      },
      {
        text: 'Reset Columns',
        action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
          table.colReorder.reset();
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  table.buttons(1, null).container().appendTo(
    table.table().container()
  );



  columnDefs: [{
    targets: 1,
    render: function(data, type, row) {
      return type === 'display' && data.length > 5 ?
      data.substr(0, 5) + '…' :
      data;
    }
  }]



  $(table.table().container()).on('keyup', 'tfoot input', function() {
    table
    .column($(this).data('index'))
    .search(this.value)
    .draw();
  });

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try redrawing the table after reset:

```
text: 'Reset Columns',
        action: function(e, dt, node, config) {
          table.colReorder.reset();
          table.draw();
        }
```

Comment: same results as the original issue

Comment: strange... try table.fnFilterClear();